# TensorFlow convert into predicted temperature

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I recently started learning TensorFlow. I followed the tutorial on https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series and decided to dig further into the RNN / LSTM Model.
The tutorial explains, how to use and plot the model, but I would also like to try to convert an output value into a "real" value.
How do I extract the predicted value from the test-dataset and convert it back into a temperature?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `model.predict()` to feed any arbitrary input into your model (doesn’t have to come from your testing dataset). It will return a prediction for that input.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So I can just use model.predict() on the test dataset? How do I convert the output tensor back into a temperature value?

Comment: You can call model.predict() on batches of input or even on a single instance (this works fine, although the TensorFlow documentation recommends to use model() for smaller numbers of input). What I've done in a project to illustrate things is to construct a tensor with one particular input and feed this into model.predict(). To do that, you need to get the input shape right, i.e., the tensor must have the same dimensionality as the individual instances in your training set. model.predict() will then return a prediction for that input. What that looks like depends on how you set up the ANN.